# How do I solve this float error when using bertopic

Tags: python, pandas, bert-language-model, deb

I am getting `sequence item 18: expected str instance, float found` error when running 1 line of code. The data source consistence of 2 columns. Column #1 is generic id of 1 through 600. The second column contains text responses. These text responses may contain floating. Is there a way to code or fix that prior to running topics, `probability = model.fit_transform(Docs)`? I am new to python and was following a guide. The guide was originally for some sort of twitter data, but I figured I would try another set of data, but didn't expect to run into a float error. Any advice would be really appreciated and help me grow a bit.

```py
pip install bertopic
visualization
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bertopic import BERTopic
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/CENSORED/Desktop/CENSORED/CENSORED", engine = 'python', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
df = df [0:600]
model = BERTopic(verbose=True)
docs = df.text.to_list()
topics, probabilities = model.fit_transform(docs)
```

```
TypeError: sequence item 18: expected str instance, float found
```

Comment: Well, what is sequence item 18? Whatever data you're reading from should all be text, so this sounds more like bad data

Comment: oh shit, dude does sequence item mean #18 in the data? ah man, this explains it all

Comment: I'd guess yes; "sequence item 18", to me, indicates that it is talking about an item in a sequence with an index of 18.

Comment: `df.text.astype('str')` should fix this.

Answer (score 1):

There's a null value in your documents.
It gets read as a `NaN`, which is a float.

You can get around it coercing it to a string

```py
df['text'].astype('str')
```

but you should consider if removing these records is better.